# Database Design: Trouble Connecting Ideas

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've hit a bit of a wall ... here is my simplified schema:

```
TABLE users
id

TABLE assets
id
userid

TABLE presentations
id
userid
```

At this point, it's easy to create a relationship between USERS -> ASSETS and USERS -> PRESENTATIONS ... but where I run into a bit of a brain fart is when I introduce TEMPLATES for the PRESENTATIONS:

```
TABLE templates
id
```

You see, each TEMPLATE has several positions... not all TEMPLATES have the same amount of positions. Each position houses an ASSET or is empty.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out which way is the best way to connect PRESENTATIONS -> TEMPLATES (and position) -> ASSETS ... and keep in mind, not all ASSETS are associated with a PRESENTATION.

**Proposed Schema:**

```
TABLE presentations
id

TABLE templates
id

TABLE positions
id
templateid
assetid
```

But there is a problem with this. This assumes that each TEMPLATE can just a random amount of POSITIONS. Yes, a TEMPLATE has a 1 - n relationship with POSITIONS, but not really. Because a TEMPLATE wouldn't be a TEMPLATE if it wasn't repeatable. TEMPLATE 1 has 4 positions, and will always have 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's see as promised:

```
table Presentation
int id
varchar name
int fk_template (references template.id)
....

table Template
int id
varchar name
.....

table Position
int id
int zorder (if it is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd position of the given template)
int fk_template (references Template.id)
.....

table Asset
int id
varchar name
varchar description
....

table AssetForPresentation
int fk_asset (references Asset.id)
int fk_presentation (refernces Presentation.id)
int fk_position (ferences Position.id)
```

Now you have templates that have fixed positions. Every presentation uses one template. For every presentation and every position inside this presentation you can define one asset or none. You must make sure that in table AssetForPresentation only position ids are used that are actually member of the template used by this presentation. If a position of a given presentation has no asset, just don't create an entry in table AssetForPresentation.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a way to avoid using a connecting table (AsetForPresentation)?

Comment: Why avoid it? A few large tables with lots of columns and repeated data are a sure sign of lousy design

Comment: Just wondering if it's possible to not have to create a table for that relationship. I'm thinking it's not.

Comment: It always is if you break with NF. You could also make one huge table with columns user, presentation, template, position, asset and repeat a lot of data. But no sense there in using a RDB.

Comment: Yeah no, I just want the most simple, ORM friendly schema.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly:

```
table templates
id

table position
id
fk_templateid 
fk_assetid
```

Being fk_assetid nullable to allow positions without assets.

And if each presentation uses exactly one template add a fk in table presentation referencing templates.id.

Comment: Your TABLE "position" ... is that first FK supposed to be "fk_templateid"?

Comment: I hadn't thought of abstracting the actual position... And you're say that for each TEMPLATE that is created, any number of new POSITIONS would be created for that TEMPLATE?

Comment: Well, as it is a 1-n relation it cries for a own table.

Comment: So you're saying: PRESENTATIONS, TEMPLATES, POSITIONS, ASSETS would be the tables needed? I think I'm so afraid of making too many levels of tables, but if the needs calls for it...

Comment: There is no other sensible way to implement a 1-n (1 template has n positions) relation in a RDB.

Comment: But see, I'm not sure this will work... TEMPLATES have several positions, but the positions don't change. A TEMPLATE is a TEMPLATE. I still have to have a record of what positions belong to a TEMPLATE.

Comment: That "record" is the fk referencing table template.

Comment: Okay, a TEMPLATE is something that needs to be repeatable. A position isn't created with a specific asset in mind... a position is really "set" for a TEMPLATE. TEMPLATE 1 has 4 positions, and each PRESENTATION is different... meaning different assets for a TEMPLATE.

Comment: OK, now I get you, I will write another answer. But probably tomorrot.

Comment: If you still remember what you were thinking as a solution, I'm very anxious to see what you have! :)